# Execute a terminal command

Tags: objective-c, linux, macos

I want to run a terminal command from my objective-c project.

When I run it from the teminal I use :

```
cd /Users/user/Desktop/project/;ant release
```

now I used this in the Objective-C project:

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"cd /Users/user/Desktop/project/;ant"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"release", nil]];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];

[task launch];

NSData *data = [[pipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];

[task waitUntilExit];
[task release];

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"got\n%@", string);
[string release];
```

and after `[task launch];` I get error:

```
launch path not accessible
```

## Edit

I tried to use this command for check:

```
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/user/Desktop/Czech/"];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/ls"];
```

and it still give me a warning :

```
working directory doesn't exist.
```

Comment: Regarding the `working directory doesn't exist` message: check the path in the call to `setCurrentDirectoryPath:`, are there any spelling errors?

Comment: Do not try with `ls` command. Try something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the working directory in a different way:

```
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/user/Desktop/project"];
```

Then change your `setLaunchPath:` call to point to the location of the actual executable:

```
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/ant"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you try and execute a shell line here.

Try and change the directory first (to `/Users/blabla`) and then issue your `ant` command. My guess here is that the program tries to find a command named `cd /Users/user/Desktop/project/;ant`.