# Launching Java application from Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm trying to make a simple frontend in objective C, and I'm pretty new to it. What I want to do is to be able to open my jar file with an argument. I've tried using the terminal command option as outlined here:

[Execute a terminal command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503470/execute-a-terminal-command)

but that doesn't seem to be working. I don't think that it likes calling java directly like that. Just for kicks, I'm including the code I've used so far in case there's a simple fix to make it work. If there's another way that it more proper, please let me know.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *currentpath;

    filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    task.launchPath = currentpath;//[currentpath stringByAppendingString:@"/;java"];
    task.arguments = @[@"-jar", @"PolyGlot.jar", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", argv]];
    task.standardOutput = pipe;

    [task launch];

    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    [file closeFile];

    NSString *grepOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog (@"grep returned:\n%@", grepOutput);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: On the [task launch] line, I'm getting the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn:
>   error 13'

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: *"doesn't seem to be working*" What's the problem exactly?

Comment: On the [task launch] line, I'm getting the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13'